# Is there an AppleScript command to zoom a sheet in Numbers?

Tags: applescript, numbers

I think the answer to this question is "no", as I've not found any mention of it in the Numbers dictionary, but I thought I would ask here in case it's an undocumented feature.

I have a fairly large Table that I'm using AppleScript on. I'm running a script like this on it and have noticed it's very slow when the zoom level is low. When I set it to 400% it runs 100x faster.

```
repeat with i from 2 to the count of cells of column "E"
    set the value of cell i of column "E" to (the value of cell i of column "C")
end repeat
```

So is there a way to automated this in AppleScript so that before I enter that repeat loop I can set zoom to 400%?

I would like to add that I can't use System Events in this case as I need it to happen in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I should have clarified that I need this to happen in the background. I think all these options require the activation of Numbers which doesn't work for my situation.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/487030/can-i-use-applescript-to-click-buttons-in-background for background scripting.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, I will try it that way.

Comment: OK I will try it. Can you post your answer again please?
Sometimes we can't know all the necessary parts of the question until we know what the possible solutions will be.

Comment: BTW @user3439894 I'm surprised it works so well. I had mistakingly thought that anytime you used system events that the application had to be activated first but it does it correctly without even showing the app or needing to be in the foreground. This will be very helpful in accessing other features in Numbers that don't have native AppleScript support. Where can I learn more about the syntax for System Events?

Comment: RE: "Where can I learn more about the syntax for System Events? " --  I'd start with reviewing the **AppleScript** _dictionary_ for **System Events** in the **Library** in **Script Editor** (**⇧⌘L** ).  From there, to be honest, I'd just search as needed and read whatever you can find.  Quite a bit of what one needs is already out there on the **Internet**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* uses **UI Scripting**, however as tested it did not require **Numbers** to be frontmost.  In other words it will work in the background, albeit I did see the **Zoom** *menu* pop up briefly but the *window* stayed in the background.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Assumes Numbers spreadsheet is already opened.   

my zoomToPercent("400%")

on zoomToPercent(p)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell group 2 of ¬
            toolbar 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            application process "Numbers"
            
            set percentButton to ¬
                the first menu button ¬
                    whose name contains "%"
            
            click percentButton
            click menu item p of menu 1
            
        end tell
    end tell
end zoomToPercent
```

**Notes:**

Set it up as a *handler* so you can pass it a new *value* after the processing at the higher percent.

You can change `window 1` to e.g. `window "Untitled"` or whatever the name of the *window* is.

The *handler* also could be modified to take a second *parameter*, being the *name* of the *window*.

**Note:** The **Zoom** *menu* on the **Toolbar** and the *value* passed must be one that shows on the **Zoom** *menu* on the **Toolbar**.

**UI Scripting** can be *kludgy* and is prone to failure. It can easily break as the **UI** changes in different version of the product, or change the **user** can make, timing issues, etc.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown above, was tested in **Script Editor** with **Numbers** version 10.2 (7028.0.88) under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

---

Modified *handler* to take the *percentage* and the *name* of *window*:

```applescript
--  # Assumes Numbers spreadsheet is already opened.   

my zoomToPercent("400%", "Untitled")

on zoomToPercent(p, n)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell group 2 of ¬
            toolbar 1 of ¬
            window n of ¬
            application process "Numbers"
            
            set percentButton to ¬
                the first menu button ¬
                    whose name contains "%"
            
            click percentButton
            click menu item p of menu 1
            
        end tell
    end tell
end zoomToPercent
```

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: I just got this error. It was working for a while but then this:

Can’t get window 1 of «class pcap» "Numbers" of application "System Events". Invalid index. (-1719)

Comment: @Steve Torrence, What version of **macOS** are you running and version of **Numbers**?

Comment: Big Sur 11.5 (latest)
Numbers 11.1 (7031.0.102)
It seems to happen if I'm using spaces (which I always do) and I'm currently on another space. Maybe there is "on error" I can add to it so it doesn't interrupt the execution of the rest of the script? Because it's not necessary it always works but when it does, it speeds up that part of the script 100%.

Comment: I put around it:
Try
…
End Try

Maybe that will work.

Comment: Yes, **macOS Big Sur** has caused many a _script_ that worked well in previous versions of **macOS**. One workaround when manipulating thing in **System Preferences** > using **UI Scripting** the to add a `launch` _command_ as the line of _code_ in the `tell application "System Events"` _block_, I do not think that applicable here. It's most likely  because it was in a different **Space**. As far as _error handling_ goes, that is why I put what I do at the end of my **AppleScript** answers.

Comment: Will wrapping it with Try…End Try allow it to continue in case of an error?

Comment: Yes, wrapping `my zoomToPercent("400%")` in a `try` _statement_ will allow the rest of the _script_ to continue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128831/discussion-between-steve-torrence-and-user3439894).